# Why does GetClusterShape return null when the cluster specification was retrieved through the GetClusteredShapes method?

Tags: javascript, virtual-earth

Suppose I have a virtual earth shape layer called `shapeLayer1` (my creative energy is apparently at an alltime low).

When i call the `GetClusteredShapes` method I get an array of `VEClusterSpecification` objects that represent each and every one of my currently visible clusters; no problem there. But when I call the `GetClusterShape()` method it returns null... null! Why on earth would it do that? I used firebug to confirm that the private variable of the `VEClusterSpecification` that's supposed to hold a reference to the shape is indeed null so it's not the method that's causing the problem.

[Some have suggested](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vemapcontroldev/thread/58bb9ba5-d620-4c77-bf37-e4c5c8fbc914/#6c14c0be-de69-4ccb-89a1-9c8f72a612ef) that this is actually documented behavior

> Returns **null** if a VEClusterSpecification object was returned from the VEShapeLayer.GetClusteredShapes Method

But looking at the current [MSDN documentation for the VEShape class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc980821.aspx) it says:

> Returns if a VEClusterSpecification object was returned from the VEShapeLayer.GetClusteredShapes Method

Is this a bug or a feature? Is there any known workarounds or (if it is a bug) some plan on when they are going to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I know it sux... I'm still looking at the code but from what I can tell they want you to set the custom stuff using the VEClusteringOptions callback method. This doesn't work for for me because I'm using a custom infobox but it may help someone else, using the method below you have complete access to the shapes inside the cluster.

```
function clusteringCallback(clusters)
{
   for (var i=0; i < clusters.length; ++i)
   {
        var cluster = clusters[i];
        var clusterShape = cluster.GetClusterShape();
        clusterShape.SetCustomIcon("<div class='cluster'><div class='text'>"+cluster.Shapes.length+"</div></div>");
        clusterShape.SetTitle("This is my Cluster #" + i);
        clusterShape.SetDescription("This cluster has " + cluster.Shapes.length + " shapes in it!");
   }
}

function SetClustering() 
{
    var options =  new VEClusteringOptions();
    options.Callback = clusteringCallback;
    shapeLayer.SetClusteringConfiguration(VEClusteringType.Grid, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the layer id from the layer which the clustershape belongs to you can do it like this:

```
var layerId = clusters[i].Shapes[0].GetShapeLayer().MsnId;
```

if you find another way, please inform us ;-)